# Exponential decay learning rate parameters of Adam optimizer in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tf.keras

Consider the following information:

- initial learning rate: 0.0002
- decay coefficient: 0.7
- ephocs: 70

My problem is to choose the decay step in such a way that the decay occurs every two epochs. How can I fix this in Keras?

This is the formula of the exponential decay learning rate:

[click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvvcG.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the [ExponentialDecay](https://keras.io/api/optimizers/learning_rate_schedules/exponential_decay/) `LearningRateScheduler` could be used.  To decay every two epochs, the `decay_steps` should be `num_steps_per_epoch * 2`.  Also provide the `staircase` parameter as `True` so that the learning rate decays discretely.

Something like this (I didn't run this code):

```
initial_learning_rate = 0.0002
steps_per_epoch = ...
lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate,
    decay_steps=steps_per_epoch * 2,
    decay_rate=0.7,
    staircase=True)
```

Then pass `lr_schedule` to `Adam` using the `learning_rate` parameter.

Comment: What value do you typically choose for steps_per_epoch?

Comment: That depends on your dataset size and batch size.  In your question you said that you wanted to update every two epochs.  So, let's say you have 1000 samples and a batch size of 20, then an epoch would be 1000 / 20 = 50 steps (`steps_per_epoch = 50`).

Comment: In my case I have 1905 samples and batch size = 32, so steps_per_epoch = 1905/32 = 59,53 => 60 ??

Comment: Yep.  I think that `decay_steps` needs to be an integer because the `staircase` parameter basically tells the `ExponentialDecay` schedule to do integer division in the `(global_step / decay_steps)` part of the calculation from your image.  I would pass `decay_steps=119` (59.5 * 2).

Comment: That should only be the case if, e.g., `steps_per_epoch` is not an int already, but that's neither here nor there.  Does my answer answer your question?  If so, consider marking it as such.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't matter if `decay_steps` is an int or not.  The code just does a `floor` if `staircase` is `True`: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.5.0/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/learning_rate_schedule.py#L185